# Specific case of using articles in mathematics

Tags: articles, mathematics

My czech book on English in mathematics has a section about choosing the right article. It says:

> Use the indefinite article when you are referring to each element of a
>   class. For example: Mersenne primes are related to perfect numbers.

And then:

> Use the definite article when you are referring to all elements of a class. For example: The harmonics numbers are the numbers H^n for \alpha > 1 defined by the formula...

I am deeply confused since I do not get the difference between the examples. I do not get the difference between each element and all elements neither.

Comment: That's really unhelpful. "Use indefinite article" [sic] with a plural example. And both those sentences should start with "Use ***the*** ... article when..."

Comment: Edited. Why do you think it is unhelpful?

Comment: It's unhelpful because the indefinite article (*a/an*) cannot be used with plurals. Have a look at our standard go-to post: [Simple rules for articles](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a).

Comment: Are those sentences actually quotations in English from your book? Or are they written in Czech and you have translated them into  English for this question?

Comment: The article you need to be careful about in maths is "the."Consider:

Comment: "Given a real-valued function f and a number c and a number L we say THE limit of f at c is L provided..."     Given the real -valued function f  and the number c and the number L we say A limit of f at c is L provided.... Here I swapped "the" and "a" throughout. Only the switch in CAPITAL LETTERS is mathematically wrong, because "the" promises that f does not have two limits at c, but "a" does not make this promise.

Comment: A traditional analysis of English articles assigns the plural indefinite article a zero form.  So the Czech book's example is reasonable.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes it is direct quotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks rather confusing indeed: the chosen examples do little to illustrate the concept as they seem to refer both to *all* elements of a class, and the first one doesn't contain any article worth mentioning. Hopefully the following examples may help clarify the point a little better.

*Indefinite article*: "**An** element of the harmonic series has the form 1/n". Of course this refers actually to *all* elements of the harmonic series, but formally only a generic one is considered. '**An**' might be easily replaced by '**each**' without altering the sense of the sentence.

*Definite article*: "By convention **the** first prime number is 2, although 1 fits the definition as well". Here we are talking about a *specific* element of a set, the first one.

*Definite article*: "**The** elements of an abelian group obey the axiom of commutativity". Here we are explicitly considering *all* elements of the group collectively rather than a single, generic one.

Comment: How would you argue the following example: Mersenne primes are related to perfect numbres. It seems to me like it should go with the definite article, but my book says it shouldnt.

Comment: That's a tricky point. I'm afraid I cannot provide a decent explanation, but hopefully someone else will. It is **not** because of the proper name (I would say "_prime numbers are..._", not "_**the** prime numbers are..._"), yet saying "_elements of the Klein group are..._" without a _the_ would feel very wrong.